# Android Swap Up Down Left and Right to change Activity/Fragment

Tags: android

I am building a custom Home Launcher that will have the following navigation logic:
[image]

The Slide Right and Left I think it can be easily achieved using a ViewPager, so the center Activity is a ViewPager and when the user Swipe Left or Right the new Fragment is loaded. But how can I also achieve the Swipe Up and Down in the same Activity?
Actually what I need is a multi-direction ViewPager. Does it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found on the internet one day a swipe listener that allows to do just that:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    // Fields:
    /** Whether a swipe motion has been detected */
    protected boolean isSwipeDetected = false;
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;


    // Constructors:
    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final int HORIZONTAL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 0;
        private static final int HORIZONTAL_SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 0;
        private static final int VERTICAL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int VERTICAL_SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {    // More of a horizontal movement
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > HORIZONTAL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > HORIZONTAL_SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            isSwipeDetected = true;
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            isSwipeDetected = true;
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } else {    // Vertical movement
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > VERTICAL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > VERTICAL_SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            isSwipeDetected = true;
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            isSwipeDetected = true;
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        boolean isSwipe = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return isSwipe;
    }
}
```

Set it as the OnTouchListener for your main activity's layout and implement your logic in the onSwipe* methods.

Comment: Note that you can play a bit with the parameters to change the sensitivity of the swipe events, but don't try to play with the onDown() method or change the overall logic - you won't get the desired behavior.

Comment: That's super, than I can load fragments and use animations so that it looks like a real swipe. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

```
I found a Solution you can add onTouchListener in your View:-


footerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.MODE, Mode.ONLINE);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.NOTES_DATA, notesDataModel);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.CONTENT_DATA, contentListModel);
                    startActivity(intent);


                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is Simple way to animate upward any activity on intent.Please try this